# Comparing Variables within Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, equality

Ok. So I thought this would have been easy, but I am hitting a snag.

```
$var = (Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\SAP\General" -Name "BrowserControl")."BrowserControl"
$var2 = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\SAP\General"
$var3 =  @('1','0')
#if (($var -eq ($var3 -join'')))
#if (Compare-Object -IncludeEqual $var $var3 -SyncWindow 0)
if ($var -eq $var3)
{
    Write-Output "Registry hive exists"
    exit 1
}   
else 
{
    Write-Output "Registry hive doesn't exists"
    #New-ItemProperty -Path $var2 -name "BrowserControl" -Value "1" -PropertyType "DWORD" -Force | Out-Null
    
}
```

If 1 or 0 is returned from BrowserControl, I want it to be a match. If anything else is returned, no match.
If BrowserControl is set to 1, it works. If it is set to 0 or any number other than 1 it doesn't match.
I know I can use else-if and add a couple more lines of code, but I was really wanting to get this to work.
As you can see, I have tried different comparison methods. I also tried (0,1), ('0','1'), 0,1 for var3. None of those worked either.
So... what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot meaningfully use an *array* as the *RHS* (right-hand side) of the `-eq` operator**.<sup>[1]</sup>

However, **PowerShell has *dedicated operators* for testing whether a given single value is *contained in* a collection** (more accurately: equal to one of the elements of a collection), namely **[`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin)** and its operands-reversed counterpart, **[`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains)**.

In this case, `-in` makes for more readable code:

```bash
if ($var -in $var3) # ...
```

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell quietly *accepts* an array (collection) as the RHS, but - uselessly - *stringifies* it, by concatenating the elements with a single space by default. E.g., `'1 2' -eq 1, 2` yields `$true`.

By contrast, using an array as the *LHS* of `-eq` *is* meaningfully supported: the RHS scalar then acts as a *filter*, returning the *sub-array* of equal LHS elements; e.g. `1, 2, 3, 2 -eq 2` returns `2, 2`</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much!! I had/have no idea what RHS/LHS are, but I can just google that. You response is the correct answer, but you already knew that.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Dullawolf; my pleasure. RHS and LHS simply mean "right-hand side" and "left-hand side" and refer to  the position (side) of an operand of a binary (two-operand) infix operator such as `-eq` in PowerShell - see the [Sides of an equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation) Wikipedia article.